# How to have two configurations for login in a spring-boot application and retrieve csrf token successfully?

Tags: angularjs, spring, spring-security, spring-boot, csrf

I have a spring-boot application with AngularJS front end. Application has two login options in the login page. One is using google authentication and the other is a form login which validates the user against a local ldap server. Google authentication works fine. I can't get the form login to work and it shows me the 403 error when I use the POST method. If I try with GET it lets anyone login and does not do the validation against ldap.

This is the exact error I get:
This is the error I am getting when i do POST even if the user credentials are correct or not. `There was an unexpected error (type=Forbidden, status=403). Invalid CSRF Token 'null' was found on the request parameter '_csrf' or header 'X-XSRF-TOKEN'`

But I can see the following in the request header when I analyse the header details in browser:

```
Cookie: JSESSIONID=B594899731C57C09E0B514F798AE248F; screenResolution=1440x900; XSRF-TOKEN=c0bf5124-0085-4181-b3f0-df72075f985b
```

Form Data
view source
view URL encoded

```
Configuration file:


    @Configuration
    @EnableWebSecurity
    public class MultiHttpSecurityConfig {

        @Configuration
        @EnableOAuth2Client                                                       
        public static class GoogleWebSecurityConfigurationAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

            @Autowired
            OAuth2ClientContext oauth2ClientContext;

            @Override
            protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
                     http.antMatcher("/**")
                    .authorizeRequests()
                        .antMatchers("/", "/index.html", "/app/**", "/bower_components/**").permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                    .and().exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(new LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint("/"))
                    .and().logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/index.html").permitAll()
                    .and().csrf().csrfTokenRepository(csrfTokenRepository())
                    .and().addFilterAfter(csrfHeaderFilter(), CsrfFilter.class)
                    .addFilterBefore(ssoFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);         
            }

            @Bean
            public FilterRegistrationBean oauth2ClientFilterRegistration(
                    OAuth2ClientContextFilter filter) {
                FilterRegistrationBean registration = new FilterRegistrationBean();
                registration.setFilter(filter);
                registration.setOrder(-100);
                return registration;
            }

            private Filter ssoFilter() {
                OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter googleFilter = new OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter("/login/google");
                OAuth2RestTemplate googleTemplate = new OAuth2RestTemplate(google(), oauth2ClientContext);
                googleFilter.setRestTemplate(googleTemplate);
                googleFilter.setTokenServices(new UserInfoTokenServices(googleResource().getUserInfoUri(), google().getClientId()));
                return googleFilter;
            }

            @Bean
            @ConfigurationProperties("google.client")
            OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails google() {
                return new AuthorizationCodeResourceDetails();
            }

            @Bean
            @ConfigurationProperties("google.resource")
            ResourceServerProperties googleResource() {
                return new ResourceServerProperties();
            }

            private Filter csrfHeaderFilter() {
                return new OncePerRequestFilter() {
                    @Override
                    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                            FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
                        CsrfToken csrf = (CsrfToken) request.getAttribute(CsrfToken.class.getName());
                        if (csrf != null) {
                            Cookie cookie = WebUtils.getCookie(request, "XSRF-TOKEN");
                            String token = csrf.getToken();
                            if (cookie == null || token != null && !token.equals(cookie.getValue())) {
                                cookie = new Cookie("XSRF-TOKEN", token);
                                cookie.setPath("/");
                                response.addCookie(cookie);
                            }
                        }
                        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
                    }
                };
            }

            private CsrfTokenRepository csrfTokenRepository() {
                HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository repository = new HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository();
                repository.setHeaderName("X-XSRF-TOKEN");
                return repository;
            }
        }

        @Configuration
        public static class FormLoginWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

            @Override
            protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
                 http.antMatcher("/**")
                    .authorizeRequests()
                        .antMatchers("/", "/index.html", "/app/**", "/bower_components/**").permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated()
                        .and().formLogin()
                            .loginPage("/index.html").permitAll()
                        .and().logout()                                    
                            .logoutSuccessUrl("/").permitAll();
            }

            public void init(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

                auth.ldapAuthentication()
                    .userSearchFilter("uid={0}")
                    .groupSearchBase("ou=Groups")
                    .contextSource()
                    .url("ldap://localhost:10500/dc=xyz,dc=org,dc=fr");

            }

        }

     }

Login form is in the index.html and looks like this:

<div ng-if="!authenticated" class="container">  
            <h2 class="align">Login</h2>
            <p><a  class="btn" href="login/google">Login with Google</a></p>
            <h4 class="align">OR</h4>   
            <form role="form" action="/#/" method="post">
                <div>
                    <label for="username">Username</label>
                    <input type="text" name="username" id="uname" required autofocus>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label for="password">Password</label>
                    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" required>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label for="remember-me">Remember me</label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="remember-me" id="remember-me">
                </div>
                <button type="submit">Sign in</button>
            </form>
        </div>
```